# Parse dynamic array of objects with JQ

Tags: arrays, json, object, jq

I am trying to flatten and re-transform a JSON payload via JQ, but have been unsuccessful thus far. I have the following payload that has a dynamic number of values depending for each object underneath the `stats` field:

```
{
  "stats": [
    {
      "devid": 3,
      "key": "diskall",
      "value": [
        {
          "0": 0.0001,
          "1": 0.0001,
          "2": 0.0012,
          "3": 0.0005,
          "4": 0.0007,
          "5": 0.0013,
          "6": 0.0006000000000000001,
          "7": 0.0006000000000000001,
          "8": 0.0006000000000000001,
          "9": 0.0006000000000000001,
          "10": 0.0005,
          "11": 0.0005,
          "12": 0.0005
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "devid": 7,
      "key": "diskall",
      "value": [
        {
          "0": 0.0003,
          "1": 0.0004,
          "2": 0.0012,
          "3": 0.0005,
          "4": 0.0007,
          "5": 0.0013,
          "6": 0.00060001
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to flatten and transform the value array object keys/values to a result like below (for each value within each stat object). Basically take the key in values and place that in a field called `nodeId` and take the value and place that in a field called `value`

```
{
"devid": 3
"key": "diskall"
"nodeId": 0
"value": 0.0001
},
{
"devid": 3
"key": "diskall"
"nodeId": 1
"value": 0.0001
},
{
"devid": 3
"key": "diskall"
"nodeId": 2
"value": 0.0012
},
{
"devid": 7
"key": "diskall"
"nodeId": 0
"value": 0.0003
}
```

I was able to flatten with jq like this: `.stats | map(del(.value) + .value[])`, but I'm not sure how to approach transforming the values into their own objects as well as rename the keys/values a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.stats[]
| {devid,key} + (.value[] | to_entries[] | {nodeId: .key|tonumber, value})
```

You might wish to replace `tonumber` by `(tonumber? // .)` for robustness.